# How do I send an email with R using a Gmail, when I get this java.lang error

Tags: java, r, email

I have been working on trying to send emails from R using a gmail address, but I always get the same error code. Is there a way correcting this error. I know similar question have been asked before, but I can't get to figure it out with these answers. Thank you for your help

Also, the parameters from my google account already been adjusted.

Here is my code to send email:

```
library(mailR)
sender <- "abc@gmail.com"
recipients <- c("abc@gmail.com")
send.mail(from = sender,
          to = recipients,
          subject = "Subject of the email",
          body = "Body of the email",
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, 
                      user.name = "abc@gmail.com",            
                      passwd = "123abc", ssl = TRUE),
          authenticate = TRUE,
          send = TRUE)
```

Here is the error code

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.createMimeMessage(Email.java:1832)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.buildMimeMessage(Email.java:1268)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1436)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at RJavaClassLoader.findClass(RJavaClassLoader.java:383)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 8 more
NULL
NoClassDefFoundError (Java): javax/activation/DataHandler[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail@1ed6993a}"
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java 9 released `javax.activation` had removed.
So if you need to use Java 9 or above just install these jars

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0
  and put into `system.file("java", package = "mailR")` folder.

Comment: Thank you @zforgo, it moved thing forward, but now i have another error message that start like this  `org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at `

Comment: `ava.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
 at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials c10sm649609qkm.71 - gsmtp

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
 at `

Comment: `at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
 ... 6 more
NULL
EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465[1] "Java-Object{org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail@7adda9cc}" `

Comment: Afterward, I figure out that I needed an app password after, which worked out well.